# Should I maintain a connected GoogleApiClient while Application is alive?

Tags: android, android-service, google-api-client

I'm working on an application which uses the GoogleApiClient in back- and fore-ground components. Should I maintain a connected GoogleApiClient in my Application context, or should I connect and disconnect in every single component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anybody is wondering. I ended up with connecting and closing the connection when needed.